# Jquery how to call click on a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link with the id:

```
nyhedsklik
```

I this function that gets triggered when clicking on the link:

```
    $('a.poplight[href^=#]').click(function() {
        var popID = $(this).attr('rel'); //Get Popup Name
        var popURL = $(this).attr('href'); //Get Popup href to define size
I have just taken a part of the function for an example....
```

Now I want to make a click on the link with Jquery. Just like a user would do I have tried this which does not work:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('#nyhedsklik').trigger("click");
});
</script>
```

Comment: The `.trigger` should work. What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Why does your selector match `a.poplight[href^=#]` but then you switch to `#nyhedsklik`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the click() method with no parameters, Jquery will simulate a click...

```
$('#nyhedsklik').click();
```

Comment: setTimeout(function(){$('nyhedsklik').click();},5000) // 5 second delay

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that before you trigger `click` event on the anchor the event is attached to it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.poplight[href^=#]').click(function() {
        var popID = $(this).attr('rel'); //Get Popup Name
        var popURL = $(this).attr('href'); //Get Popup href to define size

        ...
    });

    $('#nyhedsklik').trigger("click");

    //Alternatively you can just call click method
    $('#nyhedsklik').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $("selector").click().

http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 0):

I see no errors in code posted, there should be a problem somewhere else; this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cfgUT/) works fine (it simulates click with a 5 seconds delay).

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/sAcje/